# i am not able to cite my article

Tags: citing

i am having following error while refrencing my article

You have requested document class `ieeecolor', but the document class provides`IEEEtran'.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please edit your post and attach your code. It will be helpful for us to give you a solution.

Comment: That's simply a warning that has no consequence whatsoever on typesetting; in particular nothing to do with references.